# Python increment variable with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to increase a variable in a for loop dynamicly .

first iteration: i=i+4

second iteration: i= i+5

third iteration i= i+6
....

Trying:

## first iteration

```
    for i in d:         # d has lenght 2 
      i=i+4 # i = 17 
      sheet.insert_rows(idx=i, amount=1)
```

after the first iteration the value of i is now 23.

now do this:

## second interation

```
      for i in d:         # d has lenght 2 
      i=i+5 # i = 28
      sheet.insert_rows(idx=i, amount=1)
```

Comment: `for i in d` gives `i` the values contained in `d`.

Comment: what do you mean with manage i manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate),

from docs,

> Return an enumerate object. iterable must be a sequence, an iterator,
> or some other object which supports iteration. The **next**() method
> of the iterator returned by enumerate() returns a tuple containing a
> count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from
> iterating over iterable.

```
>>> for index, i in enumerate([3, 4], start=4):
...     print(index, i)
...
4 3
5 4
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the i=i+4 operation, try this out.

```
x = 4
d = [1, 2]  # i assume you have list like this
for i in d:
    x += 1
    sheet.insert_rows(idx=x, amount=1)
```